# Ayuda con aplicacion bluetooth ionic

Tags: java, angularjs, ionic, cordova, bluetooth

estoy recién empezando con `Ionic`. Estoy intentando hacer una aplicación para conectar mi celular con mi notebook por bluetooth a traves del plugin `cordova-plugin-networking-bluetooth`. Utilizando como ayuda la web oficial del plugin: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-networking-bluetooth .

Pude listar los dispositivos que hay, y permitir al usuario seleccionar uno, pero aunque tenga los datos del dispositivo al que me quiero conectar no puedo hacerlo, me tira el siguiente error: `read failed, socket might closed or timeout, read ret: -1`.

Este es el código de la función conectar:

```js
function conectar(seleccionado){

      networking.bluetooth.connect(seleccionado.address, '7c36e530-81cd-11e6-bdf4-0800200c9a66', function (socketId) {
      // Profile implementation here.
    }, function (errorMessage) {

      var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
        title: 'Error',
        template: errorMessage
      });
    });
```

```html
<ion-list>
  <ion-item ng-repeat="device in vm.dispositivos" ng-click="vm.conectar({{device}})" href="#">
    {{device.name}}
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

Uso el ionicPopup porque no pude hacer andar la consola. Lo que no se es si estoy haciendo bien el procedimiento de conexión o si es problema de que no tengo una app en la notebook para recibir la conexión.
Espero su respuesta. Muchas gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo pude hacer siguiendo un tutorial de un servidor bluetooth java. Mi problema era que ambas tenían que tener el mismo uuid.

Comment: saludos Martin, me parece perfecto que hayas encontrado solución a tu problema, podrías compartir el tutorial que has seguido? Así ayudamos a más desarrolladores que se encuentren en la misma situación :D

Comment: Hola, gracias! El tutorial que segui para hacer la parte del servidor fue este http://luugiathuy.com/2011/02/android-java-bluetooth/ . Para la parte del cliente (Celular) lo hice por mi cuenta con Ionic viendo un poco el plugin que publique en la pregunta. Saludos